# Get combinations of a columns

Tags: mysql

I have two columns and i wanted to display all the combinations of a single columns

Table 1

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| value | 145 |
| value | 146 |
| value2 | 13 |
| value2 | 56 |
| value2 | 364 |

[image]

I have used selfjoin, but that doesnot workout.

```
SELECT a.column1 FROM table1 a CROSS JOIN table1 b where column1="value"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Please don't post sample data as images, instead post as tables or even better post code with DDL for creating your tables and insert statements that will fill them, so we don't need to manually create test environment from scratch. That will make it much more likely you will get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
CREATE TABLE Combination (Column1 VARCHAR(20), Column2 INT);

INSERT INTO Combination VALUES ('value', 145), ('value', 146),('value2', 13), ('value2', 56), ('value2', 364);

+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| value   | 145     |
| value   | 146     |
| value2  | 13      |
| value2  | 56      |
| value2  | 364     |
+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now Full SQL Code:

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT * FROM Combination WHERE Column1 = 'value') , cte2 AS (SELECT * FROM Combination WHERE Column1 = 'value2') 
SELECT CONCAT(cte1.Column2, cte2.Column2) AS Result FROM cte1 CROSS
 JOIN cte2;

+--------+
| Result |
+--------+
| 14613  |
| 14513  |
| 14656  |
| 14556  |
| 146364 |
| 145364 |
+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Update : I changed the column2 datatype to (INT).
Screenshot I got:

[image: Terminal]

Update2 requested from OP:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable (Col1 TEXT);

INSERT INTO NewTable  WITH cte1 AS (SELECT * FROM Combin WHERE Column1 = 'value') , cte2 AS (SELECT * FROM Combin WHERE Column1 = 'value2') SELECT CONCAT(cte1.Column2, cte2.Column2) AS Result FROM cte1 CROSS  JOIN cte2;
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM NewTable;
+--------+
| Col1   |
+--------+
| 14613  |
| 14513  |
| 14656  |
| 14556  |
| 146364 |
| 145364 |
+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i have the same like below

Comment: I changed the column2 datatype to INT, and tested again. I have added the screenshot: Please check it:

Comment: What if you change concat with group_concat function ? You see the result in a list  like this : '14613,14513,14656,14556,146364,145364'

Comment: sorry its my mistake, i just noticed i have the column2 is a combination of characters and numbers and special characters. but we need to filter only the "value" and "value1" from column1 and get the combinations . have updated my query

Comment: Nothing will change! Just Change the filter to value1, and make the column2 datatype either VARCHAR or TEXT. I made the test, and got the same result.

Comment: any idea how to filter duplicate entries. i am having duplicate entries in result

Comment: Put Distinct Keyword before your query like this: SELECT DISTINCT Concat(... ) .....

Comment: Is it possible to store the result in a table ? 
```create table as newtable(with……)```

Comment: Yes, You can! I updated my post and put it there! you can check it there (named Update2).

Answer (score -1):

few of them doesnot get concatinated and having this. is it possible to use case condition as well for ex:

```
CASE COLUMN2 ..
THEN
END...
SELECT CONCAT(cte1.Column2, cte2.Column2) AS Result FROM cte1 CROSS
 JOIN cte2;

| Result   | 
| -------- | 
| 001-     | 
| 123-     |
| 456-     |
| 789-     |
```